# Python нужно найти точки максимума на картинке

Tags: python, pillow

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][![введите сюда описание изображения][2]][2]

У меня есть картинка и нужно на этой картинке найти точки максимума.
Картинка чёрно-белая, пробегаемся по всем пикселям картинки и пушим в массив только пиксели чёрного цвета, использовал библиотеку pillow. Как найти точки максимума? Наведите в нужное руслом меня, какие библиотеки использовать и т.д.
Нашёл все пиксели чёрного цвета(рис. 2)
Ну и нашёл максимальную точку максимума(рис. 3)

---

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import requests

im = Image.open(requests.get('https://i1.wp.com/www.fotwaudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/noun_538697.jpg', stream=True).raw)

# im = Image.open("sin.jpg")
im = im.convert('RGB')

color_black = (0, 0, 0)
pixels_color_Black_array = []

for x in range(im.size[0]):
    for y in range(im.size[1]):
        if im.getpixel((x, y)) == color_black:
            pixels_color_Black_array.append({'x': x, 'y': y})

pixels_color_Black_array
# print(pixels_color_Black_array)

max_point = pixels_color_Black_array[0]

for pixel in pixels_color_Black_array:
    if pixel['y'] < max_point['y']:
        max_point = pixel

print(max_point)
```

---

Comment: А где ваш код? Добавьте его в вопрос. А так ну идите по строкам сверху вниз, как появится больше одной чёрной точки в строке - вот и максимумы. Надо пробовать, может чуть сложнее всё будет, но примерно так.

Comment: Спасибо, прикрепил код

Comment: Нет, код должен быть в виде текста, чтобы каждый мог его себе скопировать и покрутить всячески. Вы же не думаете, что кто-то будет с экрана код набирать, чтобы поменять в вашем коде пару строк?

Comment: Извиняюсь, поправил

Comment: @CrazyElf, здравствуйте, не подскажите как получить 4 массива пикселей из 4 графиков на основании картинки. 
https://pastenow.ru/7ba46354ace4be521e0efed60d9c6857

Comment: Ну так если навскидку идёте по x внешним циклом, а внутренним по y и как встретили чёрную точку - добавили её в массив и увеличили индекс. Блин, это надо код писать. Задайте лучше новый вопрос и приложите картинку. Может вообще готовые методы есть, а не та кустарщина, которую я предлагаю, может кроме меня ещё кто ответит тогда

Comment: @CrazyElf, я задавал и на ru.stackoverflow(ничего не ответили толком) и stackoverflow(закрыли вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70082509/python-get-the-coordinates-of-the-graph-in-a-separate-array)

Answer (score 3):

Ну на той картинке, которая у вас по ссылке скачивается, нет осевой линии, поэтому максимумы можно определять просто по факту наличия чёрного цвета. И чтобы было красивее я ищу пока количество чёрных пикселов не перестаёт расти и потом закрашиваю в красный что нашёл. Вернее, я ищу даже не чёрные, а пикселы темнее средне-серого цвета:

```
max_y = []
max_val = 0
for y in range(im.size[0]):
    s = sum(sum(im.getpixel((x, y))) < 256 * 1.5 for x in range(im.size[1]))
    if s > 0:
        if s > max_val:
            max_y.append(y)
            max_val = s
        else:
            break

for y in max_y:
    for x in range(im.size[1]):
        if sum(im.getpixel((x, y))) < 256 * 1.5:
            im.putpixel((x, y), (255, 0, 0))
```

Что получилось:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, а если допустим были бы осевые линии как это можно было бы реализовать, не подскажите?

Comment: @Vadim Ну это надо на конкретном примере смотреть. Можно задать какой-то порог для минимального кол-ва 
точек, от которого считать максимум. Ну то есть сумму не с 0 сравнивать, а с неким порогом.

Comment: спасибо, а если допустим будет как картинка №2

Comment: @Vadim Это смотря сколько максимумов вы там хотите найти. И порогом отсечения чёрный/белый там придётся поиграться.

Comment: хотелось бы все пики найти, а маленькие отбросить, подскажите как лучше сделать тут: для порога находить СКО или корреляцию использовать

Comment: @Vadim Думаю, вам всё-таки нужно задать новый вопрос (но дать ссылку на этот вопрос тоже). И на картинке всё-таки обозначить - что вы хотите выделить, потому что на второй картинке несколько графиков, у которых несколько изгибов, тут можно несколько по-разному считать сколько тут и каких максимумов.